# Unity3D with C# to achieve Click To Move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've a problem when I use unity3D with C# to achieve Click To Move.
It means the character move to where my mouse clicked.
But when my character move to destination,it will span itself.

I think it's perhaps wrong in this line
"controller.SimpleMove (transform.forward*speed);"
when I click to position like(20.5,10.1) with decimal point or some number I can't present in "transform.forward*speed" ,cause my character can never achieve to this position but keep trying to. So my character span and span.....
It's my guess right?
If true ,how can I fix it?

This is my Script for ClickToMove

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickToMove : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
public CharacterController controller;
private Vector3 position;
public int arrive =1;
void Start () 
{

}


void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) 
    {
        //Locate where we click
        locatePosition();
    }
    MoveToPos ();
    //Move to where we click
}
void locatePosition()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 1000)) 
    {
        position = new Vector3(hit.point.x,hit.point.y,hit.point.z);
        Debug.Log(position);
    }

}
void MoveToPos()
{   if (Vector3.Distance (transform.position, position) > 1) 
    {
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (position - transform.position);
        newRotation.x = 0f;
        newRotation.z = 0f;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime * 10);
        controller.SimpleMove (transform.forward*speed);


    }


}
}
```

Comment: You can't do it like this. You'll probably have to implement path finding and it's a kinda broad topic. What kind of game is this anyway?

Comment: You could spawn an object (invisible) at the click position, and have your character move towards that, and when it gets there, destroy the instantiated object? Otherwise there are some A* path finding assets on the store and a few tutorials. But as @walther has stated, it's a large topic!